# Wireless VGA adapter

Tags: wireless-networking, vga, laptop-display

Is there such a thing as a wireless VGA adapter that does not need drivers or software. This would need to be connected to a TV from a laptop and display the desktop. Effectively it would be like a VGA cable but without the wire.

Comment: Shopping recommendations are off topic as you can read in the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq)

Comment: Edited to make it less recommendy.

Comment: There is the Intel Wireless Display, but it only works with one laptop as it is a built-in feature.

Comment: You could buy a wireless graphics card (yes, seriously: http://www.bit-tech.net/news/hardware/2011/01/12/kfa2-announces-cable-free-graphics-card/1) although the cost is going to be a bit higher than you'd like it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current Wifi standards don't have the throughput to support a display signal stream, but you can get USB multimedia adaptors as a quick browser search will confirm - do a search for "usb multimedia link"

Comment: People like inFocus and other projector companies have offered this for a number of years, Worked with 802.11g Fit on the projector DVI port.  Now have USB device that plugs in and use 802.11n

Comment: Hmm - I'll do some digging - I understood that the devices used a proprietary protocol to reduce packet latency and other issues...